# How can I get the user ID of a client and every order they made using AGGREGATION OR WINDOW FUNCTION?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

So, I have the following table, with the userid of my clients and the timestamp of their order and the timestamp of the order delivery.

| USERID | ORDER_TIME | DELIVERY_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0033 | 2021-01-01 12:30:14 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 |
| 0011 | 2021-02-12 16:15:51 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 |
| 0040 | 2021-02-18 19:22:55 | 2021-02-18 20:00:05 |
| 0017 | 2021-03-11 22:11:56 | 2021-03-11 22:57:16 |
| 0011 | 2021-01-09 11:14:18 | 2021-01-09 11:44:01 |
| 0040 | 2021-05-06 09:12:13 | 2021-05-06 10:00:10 |
| 0033 | 2021-04-16 23:00:45 | 2021-04-16 23:45:40 |
| 0011 | 2021-03-30 17:23:45 | 2021-03-30 17:51:51 |

However, I need to query the userid and the every order and delivery for every client who made ordered two or more times. After some reading I found out window functions or aggregation functions could help me, but I just can't figure out how. I need a result like this and with the order time in ascending order:

| USERID | ORDER_TIME | DELIVERY_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011 | 2021-01-09 11:14:18 | 2021-01-09 11:44:01 |
|  | 2021-02-12 16:15:51 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 |
|  | 2021-03-30 17:23:45 | 2021-03-30 17:51:51 |
| 0033 | 2021-01-01 12:30:14 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 |
|  | 2021-04-16 23:00:45 | 2021-04-16 23:45:40 |
| 0040 | 2021-02-18 19:22:55 | 2021-02-18 20:00:05 |
|  | 2021-05-06 09:12:13 | 2021-05-06 10:00:10 |

Could you guys please help me solve this?
Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select USERID, 
  array_agg(struct(ORDER_TIME, DELIVERY_TIME) order by ORDER_TIME) STATS
from `project.dataset.table`
group by USERID 
having count(1) > 1
order by USERID
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Mikhail, do you mind helping me a little bit more? Let's suppose I now have a STATS.platform column. And in this column I have mobile, desktop and tablet. Is there a easy way to choose only those registers where the STATS.platform contains both desktop AND mobile? Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Sure. no problem. Please post new question with all these details and I will be happy to help :o)

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028045/how-to-find-a-value-in-a-column-after-ive-used-array-agg-and-struct

I really appreciate your help!