# How to find a value in a column after I've used array_agg and struct?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

After using the following code in my database, I got the following results:

```
select USERID, 
  array_agg(struct(ORDER_TIME, DELIVERY_TIME, PLATFORM) order by ORDER_TIME) STATS
from `project.dataset.table`
group by USERID 
having count(1) > 1
order by USERID
```

| USERID | STATS.ORDER_TIME | STATS.DELIVERY_TIME | STATS.PLATFORM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011 | 2021-01-09 11:14:18 | 2021-01-09 11:44:01 | mobile |
|  | 2021-02-12 16:15:51 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 | desktop |
|  | 2021-03-30 17:23:45 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 | desktop |
| 033 | 2021-01-01 12:30:14 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 | mobile |
|  | 2021-04-16 23:00:45 | 2021-04-16 23:45:40 | mobile |
| 040 | 2021-02-18 19:22:55 | 2021-02-18 20:00:05 | mobile |
|  | 2021-05-06 09:12:13 | 2021-05-06 10:00:10 ​ | desktop |

However, I only need those registers which contains both mobile AND desktop. So I need something like this, a result where there is no data for the USERID 040, because they only ordered on a mobile phone:

| USERID | STATS.ORDER_TIME | STATS.DELIVERY_TIME | STATS.PLATFORM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011 | 2021-01-09 11:14:18 | 2021-01-09 11:44:01 | mobile |
|  | 2021-02-12 16:15:51 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 | desktop |
|  | 2021-03-30 17:23:45 | 2021-02-12 17:16:51 | desktop |
| 033 | 2021-01-01 12:30:14 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 | mobile |
|  | 2021-05-06 09:12:13 | 2021-05-06 10:00:10 ​ | desktop |

How can I possibly do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simplest" way is to add few more conditions into `having` clause

```
select USERID, array_agg(struct(ORDER_TIME, DELIVERY_TIME, PLATFORM) order by ORDER_TIME) STATS
from `project.dataset.table`
group by USERID 
having count(1) > 1
and 'mobile' in unnest(array_agg(PLATFORM))
and 'desktop' in unnest(array_agg(PLATFORM))
order by USERID
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In cases when you have more such entries to compare with - you can use below version to avoid repeating similar line of code

```
select USERID, array_agg(struct(ORDER_TIME, DELIVERY_TIME, PLATFORM) order by ORDER_TIME) STATS
from `project.dataset.table`
group by USERID 
having count(1) > 1
and array_length(array_agg(distinct if(PLATFORM in ('mobile', 'desktop'), PLATFORM, null))) = 2
order by USERID
```